# Javascript - close/redirect tab BEFORE it is finished loading

Tags: javascript

anyone knows how I can either close the current tab, or better yet redirect, BEFORE it is finished loading? 
So far I have only been able to achieve those two things after the tab is finished loading.

Anyone knows about a client-side solution? Keep in mind, it's for a user script, not for my own website.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is available to you? Do you own the server or do you just want it for your own specific browser? GreaseMonkey can do it for your own browser if that is what you need: http://www.greasespot.net/

Comment: Why don't you share your attempt? Don't expect to get a software service here but only help to your structured questions. So share your code, document it and explain what is your `overflow`...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
I was planning on using Tampermonkey for Chrome for the script.
So far I have the following, this if for simply redirecting:
[code] 
var currentURL = window.location.href;
currentURL = currentURL.replace('http://url.org/', '');
window.location = "http://url.org/" + currentURL;[/code]

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind providing more information? Such as the environment that you're using, what kind of browsers are you working with? Which APIs do you plan on using? The more information you provide about the context will be more helpful in providing you with useful information.

Try:
window.close()

Comment: Hey, I'm using Chrome under Win7, using Tampermonkey for making use of the Userscript.
I've tried window.close() but it waits until the page is finished loading and then closes it.

Comment: I've never used Tampermonkey. Are you making a chrome extension?